# Categorize age ranges and display in one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to see the data as follows

```
Member   Age  Category
Test1    25    Under 30
Test2    55    51-60
Test3    67    Above 60
```

I have used the below query (from an answer to my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115780/categorize-age-ranges-and-display-in-one-column)) to calculate the age from DOB and current date and then categorize each age under one name.

This query is creating separate columns, instead I want to see all the categories under one column so that I can group this category column

```
WITH AgeData as
(
SELECT
    Username,
    Birthdate,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, GETDATE()) AS AGE
FROM @Table)
SELECT
    Username,
    Birthdate,
    Age,
    CASE
        WHEN AGE < 30 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Under 30',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS '31 - 40',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS '41 - 50',
    CASE
        WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Over 50'
FROM AgeData
```

Comment: Your `CASE` expressions are missing the `age=30` case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `CASE` expressions, one for each group, just combine them into a single expression. Then, in the `THEN` clause you can use something more descriptive to group on later. In the example below I used the column aliases you provided.

```
WITH AgeData as
(
  SELECT [Username],
         [Birthdate],
         DATEDIFF(YEAR, [Birthdate], GETDATE()) AS [AGE]
  FROM @table
),
GroupAge AS
(
  SELECT [Username],
         [Birthdate],
         [Age],
         CASE
             WHEN AGE <= 30 THEN 'Under 30' -- Edited to include 30 YO
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
             WHEN AGE BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
             WHEN AGE > 50 THEN 'Over 50'
             ELSE 'Invalid Birthdate'
         END AS [Age Groups]
  FROM AgeData
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [AgeGrpCount],
       [Age Groups]
FROM GroupAge
GROUP BY [Age Groups];
```